# When no entries in database img tag still displays empty box

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, loops

I'm having troubles with a script. The script displays images which are stored in a database. However, when there are no images in the database, it will display an empty box with an broken image icon. Is there a way to stop this?

This is the code:

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
  //retrieves json encoded array
  $.getJSON("retrieveSymbol.php", function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, field){          //loops through array
      $("#bookmarkedSymbols").append(
        //sets field as image source so that the path can be displayed as an image
        "<img src='" + field[1] + "'" + "id='symbol' />"

      );
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: did you print or echo  in the format of json_encode() from the function retrieveSymbol.php  ?. if not you should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get `json` data length and apply a check for that:-

```
<script  type="text/javascript" >
  //retrieves json encoded array
  $.getJSON("retrieveSymbol.php", function(data){
       if(data.length >0){
            $.each(data, function(i, field){ //loops through array
              $("#bookmarkedSymbols").append("<img src='" + field[1] + "'" + "id='symbol' />");
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```